# Deploying self-contained native OCaml application

Tags: linux, deployment, ocaml

I need to deploy to Linux box a native OCaml application that depends on several dynamic libraries. The idea is to prepare self-contained package (no dependencies on OCaml, OPAM etc.) that contains all stuff, and can be installed on hypothetically any modern x84 Linux box. In ideal world, there would be just a single file to be deployed and run.

The best I can think of is to deploy all needed dynamic libraries (`ldd app.native`) together with application executable and run application by means of bash script that exports `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before calling application.

Any ideas how to make it better are welcome.

**UPDATE**

Some tips:

- Use [Linux Application Checker](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb/linux-application-checker-getting-started) to verify compatibility with different Linux distributions.
- Build a binary package on stable, but a bit outdated distribution (e.g. CentOS 6 for now) to improve `libc` compatibility.
- Examples of scripts to [build](https://github.com/artemkin/git-lfs-server/blob/v0.2.3/scripts/make_release_pkg_linux.sh) a binary package, and [run](https://github.com/artemkin/git-lfs-server/blob/v0.2.3/scripts/lfs_server.sh) an executable.

Comment: Am I mistaken to think that the "OCaml" aspect is quite secondary here ? I.e. that the question could be deploying a self-contained binary on linux. If not, could you point more precisely what the problem is.

Comment: @DanielBünzli yes, you're right, OCaml is secondary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OCaml with its all static approach should already work out of box. All OCaml executables are statically linked with OCaml libraries. What concerning non OCaml dependencies, then indeed you can deploy them with a wrapper script that sets `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or you can use `rpath`, or you can `dlopen` your libraries, if it makes sense for you. In any case I strongly suggest you not to treat `libc` in a such way, i.e., do not try to install your own version of `libc`.

Comment: Can you explain what is the reason for not linking libc statically please? Thanks!

Comment: The binary version of the libc is system dependent